# Indeterminate progress indicator not animating

Tags: swift, macos, nsprogressindicator

The progress indicator does not start animating even if I use queues or sleep.

I have a function that reads contents of a directory and for each mp3 file it gets the file tags. Also, I read posts about progress indicator but nothing helped me so far.

```
{
    progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
    sleep(2)
        if let item = self.outlineView.item(atRow: self.outlineView.selectedRow)  {
             self.arrMp3File.removeAll()
            do {
                let xx = (item as! DirectoryItem).url
                let b = self.getSubDir(path: xx.path)
                print(xx.path)
                for bb in b {
                    self.getTagsFromFile(file: xx.path+"/"+bb)
                }
            }
            self.arrMp3File.sort(by: {
                $0.file < $1.file
            })
            self.loadTagsFromButton.isEnabled = true
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    self.progressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
}
```

I would like to show the animation, so the user knows the app is not frozen. If I remove stopAnimation it starts animating after the files are shown on the tableview.

I added that sleep just to check the animation.

Comment: First of all don’t `sleep`. It blocks the thread. Second of all make sure that the indicator is being accessed on the main thread. Third of all the code doesn’t seem to contain time consuming work, so the user might not notice the indicator at all.

Comment: i added that sleep just to check the animation. Also, as in the question, I tried queues. It does not animate!

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `startAnimation` on the main thread?

Comment: I tried:         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
        } and it didnt work

Comment: even on a folder with 14GB of files, i can see the mouser rainbows cursor spinning and not the one in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

```
{
    if let item = self.outlineView.item(atRow: self.outlineView.selectedRow)  {
        self.arrMp3File.removeAll()
        do {
            let xx = (item as! DirectoryItem).url
            let b = self.getSubDir(path: xx.path)
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.progressIndicator.isHidden = false
                    self?.progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
                }
                for bb in b {
                    self?.getTagsFromFile(file: xx.path+"/"+bb)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.arrMp3File.sort(by: {
                        $0.file < $1.file
                    })
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
                    self?.loadTagsFromButton.isEnabled = true
                    self?.progressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
                    self?.progressIndicator.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        }
    }   

}
```